# In Magellan / Nightwatch, if we do .waitForElementNotVisible() but the element fade out or in, does the test actually work?

Tags: nightwatch.js, magellan, magellan-nightwatch

For [`.waitForElementNotVisible(selector, 2000)`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/waitForElementNotVisible.html), supposedly, it can test whether the element is fading out in 0.75 second.

But what if our code has a bug, and it is doing the wrong thing and the element is not visible and is *fading in*?

Now, won't `.waitForElementNotVisible()` actually still succeed (and pass the test), because at time = 0, it really is not visible (because it is fading in).

In other words, `.waitForElementNotVisible()` can succeed no matter what?

(There can be two situations, one is JavaScript adjusting the opacity every 33ms, for example, and the other case is CSS transition).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an assertion so you should use expect/assert api instead:

```
browser.waitForElementNotVisible(selector, 2000)
```

be

```
browser.expect.element(selector).to.not.be.visible.after(2000);
```